# WSO2 esb 4.9.0 support for Json pub sub

Tags: wso2, publish-subscribe, wso2-esb

Currently when I setup a topic on WSO2 ESB 4.9.0, the pub/sub is only sending me the soap envelope message to the subscriber end-point. Can we setup the ESB in a way that we send the incoming message as is?

When I send a message to publish on a topic as below, I am getting the below soap envelope response to all subscribers

```
POST to Topic
POST /TriggerTopic HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.224.234.34:8280
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3453ddc5-a279-203a-fecf-38e81bd3ba8b

{"value":"some value"}
```

RESPONSE received by SUBSCRIBERS from TOPIC.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><ns:topic xmlns:ns="http://wso2.org/ns/2009/09/eventing/notify">/TestTopic</ns:topic></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><value>some value</value></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there a way that we can pass the request object message as is to all the subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscriber must specify the content type as application/json

Sample publisher :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Publisher" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="jms:/dynamicTopics/TESTTOPIC?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myTopicConnectionFactory"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Sample subscriber :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Subscriber" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <description>subscriber</description>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/json</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myTopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">topic</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">TESTTOPIC</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Send this json payload to `http://localhost:8280/services/Publisher` with SoapUI : `{"value":"some value"}`

find log : `INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: ID:xxx-59490-1467971573210-1:2:1:4:1, Direction: request, Payload: {"value":"some value"}`

Comment: there is no source view to subscribe with these settings, where do we define these settings? Is there an api to subscribe to to topics?

Comment: Not sure to understand...  My samples are two proxy services and you can find the list of properties in docs.wso2.org

Comment: I take it that we need to have JMS installed for this to get this working? Can we have a similar publisher and subscribe for RabbitMQ messaging queue?

Comment: I am getting the below error on from the above suggestion [2016-07-27 10:56:12,376] ERROR - JMSOutTransportInfo Couldn't locate the JMS de
stination dynamicTopics/TestTopic of type generic extracted from the URL jms:/dy
namicTopics/TestTopic?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myTopicConnectionFactory
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dynamicQueues/dynamicTopics/TestTopic]
 is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dynamicQueues].

Comment: Getting error    [2016-07-27 14:07:57,729]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/StockQuoteProxy, Fro
m: 172.21.168.117, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' seque
nce, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error during sending message out
, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapen
v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: JMS transportReceiver in axis2.xml for ActiveMQ : <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
  <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
</parameter>